# Do the customers always want the same thing?

Tags: delicious-emily-true-love

In [Delicious: Emily's True Love](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delicious_%28series%29#Delicious:_Emily.27s_True_Love), there is a trophy called "Woman's Intuition" - the description says "Have a complete order on your tray before the order is placed, 2 times in a row."

This strikes me as something that would just happen by chance, unless each customer always wants a specific dish - then you would be able to predict it when they walked in the door.

Is this actually a trophy I can plan for? Or is it just something that I might randomly get if I am lucky?

Comment: In the absence of luck, you need intuition :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This trophy is actually easy if you do it on the day that Emily serves churros in her restaurant. Just have 2 churros on your tray at all times.

Answer (score 1):

On the very first day in the first restaurant, just make sure to always have one of the cookie, the cheesecake and the tea on your tray all the time.  You can remove them if someone orders something different, but be sure to restock them again.  Sooner or later, someone is going to come in and order a combination two of those items, since there's hardly anything else on the menu to choose from at that point.